# Real Analysis/Probability - Sequence (Verify solution?)

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

**QUESTION::**

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ , ... $X_n$ be IID random variables with

P($X_i$ = 1) = P($X_i$ = -1) = $p$

and P($X_i$ = 0) = $1- 2p$  $\forall i = 1, ... , n$

Define $a_n$ = P ($\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = 1$) ; $b_n$ = P ($\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = -1$) ; $c_n$ = P ($\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = 0$)

Estimate convergence of $ a_n , b_n ,  c_n $ as $ n \to \infty$

**SOLUTION ::**
$a_n = p^n = b_n $ and $c_n = (1-2p)^n$

As $ n \to \infty$

$ a_n \to 0 , b_n \to 0 ,  c_n \to 1$

Is this the right approach ? Or is there something missing ?

Comment: How did you get $a_n=p^{n}$? I fact, $a_2=2p^{2}$.

Comment: If an event were to occur twice - it would be p*p right?

Comment: $a_n=\sum \binom {n} {k}$ where the sum is taken over all even integers $k$ between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: $X_1X_2=1$ if either $X_1=X_2=1$ or $X_1=X_2=-1$.

Comment: I don't understand why you'll take the sum of all even integers. Is it for the (-1 * -1) combination ? If yes, then how do I compute the convergence of series $a_n$ ?

Comment: For any even integer $k \leq n$ we can consider the possibility of $k$ of the random variables being $-1$ and the rest $+1$. You have to add the probabilities of these over all such $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$c_n=1-P\left(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\neq0\right)=1-(2p)^n$$

As Kavi made clear in his comments also your calculations of $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not correct.

Further note that $a_n+b_n+c_n=1$ for every $n$.

Try to prove that $a_n=b_n$ for every $n$ which leads to $a_n=b_n=\frac12(1-c_n)$.

Comment: I think $c_n=(1-2p)^{n}$ is not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. Repaired now.

Comment: $+1$ from me. Nice observation.

Comment: Typed the value for $c_n$ wrong ! I'll get to that. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You are welcome.